# Solving $x + r\ln(x) = c$ using Lambert's W function?

Tags: lambert-w

A very elementary question, I am sure.
I would like to solve
$x + r \ln(x) = c$
where $c>1$ and $r<1$.
(There is a unique solution for $c>1,$ and the LHS is convex, btw.)
By "solve", I mean not numerically, but expressing the solution in terms of known functions, preferably something built-in in MATLAB.
Now, as far as I see, I cannot use Lambert's functions (either branch) because I get imaginary solutions that way.
Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: $x/r+\ln(x/r)=c/r-\ln(r)$, then you can use the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it to $x^r e^x = e^c \Rightarrow \frac{x}{r} e^{\frac{x}{r}} = \frac{e^{\frac{c}{r}}}{r}$. Thus $x = r W(\frac{e^{\frac{c}{r}}}{r})$.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, I had a typo and meant $x-r\ln x$, not a plus sign (otherwise the function is not convex but concave, btw; I also forgot to mention that I needed x in (0,1)), and this is what was causing me to be outside of the domain of W and get a complex branch of W.  But I rechecked my computations, a and I found that I had made a silly mistake!  - the conditions $r<1$ and $c>1$ insure that we are in the domain.  Thanks so much, in any event!